# XAML/WPF designer cannot resolve a custom MarkupExtension that takes a StaticResource as an argument

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I'm having a problem with a custom resource extension I've created, when it's used with a StaticResource as its argument.
According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/markup-extensions-and-wpf-xaml this should work:
"Nesting of multiple markup extensions is supported, and each markup extension will be evaluated deepest first."
And indeed it does work at runtime. But at design time I find that the inner StaticResource extension is not resolved - 
instead the StaticResource extension itself is passed in to custom MarkupExtension which does not work.

I've cut down to the absolute minimum to demonstrate the problem:

1) Create new WPF app "TestApp"

2) Create new class TestExtension that simply returns its argument from ProvideValue():

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class TestExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public TestExtension(object param) { _originalValue = param; }
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) { return _originalValue; }
        private object _originalValue;
    }
}
```

3) Add a resource to the main window and use it as an argument to the extension:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <sys:Double x:Key="TestResource">99</sys:Double>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Background="Red" Width="{local:TestExtension {StaticResource TestResource}}" Height="99" />

</Window>
```

Build and run and it works fine - but in the designer the width of the Grid is "Auto" instead of 99, and in the editor the Width property is squigglied with the error 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' is not a valid value for property 'Width'.

You might think you could just detect this case and call ProvideValue() on the passed in StaticResourceExtension like so:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace WPFGUI.MarkupExtensions
{
    public class TestExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public TestExtension(object param)
        {
            _originalValue = param;
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (_originalValue.GetType() == typeof(StaticResourceExtension))
            {
                _originalValue = (_originalValue as StaticResourceExtension).ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
                throw new XamlParseException("This exception will not hit because the above line does not execute at design time.");
            }

            return _originalValue;
        }

        private object _originalValue;
    }
}
```

...but that doesn't work either. The designer stops running TestExtension:ProvideValue() when it hits the call to StaticResourceException:ProvideValue().

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I've found a way:

```
public class TestExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public TestExtension(object param)
    {
        _param = param;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (_param is StaticResourceExtension || _param is DynamicResourceExtension)
        {
            IProvideValueTarget pvt = (IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));
            object key = (_param as StaticResourceExtension)?.ResourceKey ?? (_param as DynamicResourceExtension)?.ResourceKey;
            return (pvt.TargetObject as FrameworkElement)?.FindResource(key) ?? (pvt.TargetObject as FrameworkContentElement)?.FindResource(key);
        }
        return _param;
    }

    private object _param;
}
```